# Dois foreachs php - Dados duplicados

Tags: php, array, foreach

Tenho dois selects que me retornam duas arrays e preciso percorrê-las, na mesma tabela, porém os registros estão sendo duplicados. Como posso resolver essa questão da melhor forma ?

Segue o exemplo:

```
 <?php
                         foreach ($contratantes as $contratante) {
                             foreach ($contratados as $contratado) {
                                 ?>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td><?= $contratante['dataContratacao'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?= $contratante['anuncioContratante'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?= $contratante['tipoAnuncio'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?= $contratado['anuncioContratado'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?= $contratado['tipoAnuncioContratado'] ?></td>
                                     <td><?= $contratado['login'] ?></td>
                                     <td>Opções</td>


                                 </tr>

                             <?php
                             }
                         }
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos caminhos mais práticos sem mudar demais seu código é usar um loop só, e usar o índice nos *arrays* originais:

```
<?php
    $count = count($contratantes);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i ) {
?>
      <tr>
          <td><?= $contratantes[$i]['dataContratacao'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $contratantes[$i]['anuncioContratante'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $contratantes[$i]['tipoAnuncio'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $contratados[$i]['anuncioContratado'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $contratados[$i]['tipoAnuncioContratado'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $contratados[$i]['login'] ?></td>
          <td>Opções</td>
      </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Estou partindo do pressuposto que os tamanhos dos *arrays* são iguais.

Comment: Então, funciona quando eu não tenho algum ID repetido, quando algum id se repete em outro registro retorna esse erro: Undefined offset: 2

Comment: Eu ainda não tinha editado... Foi agora

Comment: Pelo que vc colocou na pergunta, acho que o problema está em outra parte do seu código. Provavelmente você quer um JOIN no DB, mas está tentando fazer no PHP uma relação, em vez de fazer direto no select. Mas não tenho certeza se é isso. De qq forma, não me parece correto usar arrays pra isso.

Comment: Se for isso, veja se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70 - se não for isso, melhor por o pedaço do código que monta os arrays na pergunta também, ou preferencialmente fazer um [mcve] do problema.

Comment: O join tá funcionando como deveria pelo banco, normalmente... Só que pra montar essa tabela, eu uso dois métodos oriundos de dois joins... até aí beleza, tentei usar dois foreach, deu erro... Fiz o que você sugeriu e pareceu ter resolvido, só que ao adicionar dados na tabela, alguns do registros nessa consulta dá  Undefined offset, pode não ser pelo motivo que falei dos ids

Comment: undefined offset pode ser array mais curta que a outra. Teria que ver os a parte que monta os arrays pra saber. Sem ver o trecho do código que faz o join e pega os arrays, fico de mãos atadas pra ajudar. Normalmente nesse caso não precisaria de dois arrays. Poderia pegar do DB e já jogar na tela

Comment: Cara, descobri o causador do problema do offset, era um array_search que estava usando antes de interar a array, foi uma solução que estava testando antes de perguntar aqui... Tirei isso e funcionou como deveria, com a sua primeira resposta. Valeu mesmo

Comment: Quando fizer uma próxima pergunta, tente colocar mais detalhes, aí a gente pode ajudar melhor. Ao menos um pouco mais do código que trabalha com os dados do problema. Não digo por o código todo, se for muita coisa, mas geralmente pondo o trecho todo da parte envolvida ajuda não só a responder, como facilita propor certas otimizações. Estamos aqui pra ajudar, mas antes precisamos entender o que está acontecendo :)